# what is the solution for this error: [Your OS (MINGW64_NT-10.0-22621) is currently not supported]?

Tags: windows, bash, curl, git-bash, scoop-installer

I was trying to install platform.sh CLI for my computer(windows11 64-bit) with this command:
`curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/platformsh/cli/main/installer.sh | bash`
but I get this error:[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft68p.png)

what is the solution of this error?

I searched a lot about this error but I have not found any specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like you're using Git bash. Have you tried installing scoop using powershell as described in the project's [installation guide](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Install#readme)?

But if you're actually using MinGW and just looking for a package-manager, and you installed MinGW via MYSYS2, you can use `pacman` (instead of scoop) according to the top answer of this post:
[mingw-64 - Install package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618405/mingw-64-install-package).